# wordpress Featured image upload function

Tags: wordpress

I am woking on uploading feature image through JSON API in php, i am unable to work with it and cannot upload the image, the image is set in media library by me but how to set that image as feature image in a post from API.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: please elaborate your question?

Comment: Hello Jmattheis Wordpress Function Usage in medai site upload and databse insert problem

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'agency_staff', $ID );